# jQuery how to have a dynamic element chosen depending on what calls the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jQuery function:

```
$('#id_first_name, #id_last_name').blur(function (){
var box=$(this);

if(box.value.length <= 0){
    box.style.borderColor='red';
}else{
    box.style.borderColor='green';        
}

})
```

How can I make it so that when this is called in the 'id_first_name' element, box = 'id_first_name', but if its called by the 'id_last_name', box is = 'id_last_name'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***this*** keyword in jquery is the element, that caleed event.
you selector work fine but your other code is not true.

your variable *box* is jquery object and you can't use javascript method on that. you have to use jquery method too:

```
$('#id_first_name, #id_last_name').blur(function (){

   var box=$(this);

   if(box.val().length <= 0){
     box.css("border", "1px solid red");
   }else{
       box.css("border","1px solid blue")     
   }

})
```

see my code : https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/JJEwNB

Comment: Thank you for the help, you're explanation made a lot of sense :)